# Python Google API Web Crawler using OAuth 2

Tags: python, api, oauth, google-api, google-api-client

I currently crawl Google API using an API Key. It turns out I'd get a lot more request quota if I use OAuth. I already applied the OAuth in my website, but I don't know how to handle the token I got from those OAuth. I can't find the sample easy enough somehow. Have seen it a little bit, but lose it right away. Google API documentation is not guiding enough.

If someone can give me a sample code, that will be awesome.

This is my current code (with no OAuth, just normal API key):

```
import pprint
from apiclient.discovery import build

service = build('plus', 'v1', developerKey="my-api-key")
person = service.people().search(query='fransisca', language='id').execute()
pprint.pprint(person)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind. Found it! It was hard. I think Google need to rethink of their own content SEO.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-gBeC9Y9cE&list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=3

See minute 2 in the video.